# Multiple File Creation In C++ Using File Handling Specific To A Particular Function Call

Tags: c++, file-handling

I want to define a function in C++ that creates a file using file handling with different name every time that function is invoked.

How can I implement it?

I am not willing to use if-else since I need a lots and lots of files.

I am totally blank. Please suggest any possible way to do it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Voted to reopen because there's standard library functionality for this. The question is broad but not too broad.

Comment: Rolled back Ivan's edit because it (1) removed a requirement (the no if-else), and (2) added a different requirement (of retaining a value between calls, which is not an observation but a new requirement, which happens to fit Ivan's own answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need *static variables*.

A static variable lets you have presistent data between function calls.

```
std::string createFileName()
{
    static int x = 0;
    std::string filename = "file_";
    filename += x;
    filename += ".txt";
    x++;
    return filename;
}
```

Each time `createFileName` is called, x will increase.
1st call returns "file_0.txt"
2nd call returns "file_1.txt"
Etc...

Comment: And why would that be?

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I have no clue about how static variables can do that for me. Moreover I want a file with different name every time the function is invoked.

Comment: @Ivan Rubinson Perfect I got What I wanted. Thanks a whole lot. :)

Comment: @Ivan Rubinson My Reputation Is Below 15 so my feedback is counted but not displayed publically it says    :(

Answer (score 1):

For temporary files use the standard library's [`tempnam` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/tmpnam), or family (e.g. `std::tmpfile`).

---

If you're not happy with `tempnam` then you can use any of these approaches:

- *Create a similar systematical name series based on e.g. a counter.*
  A counter can be passed as an explicit argument to the function, or it can be a class data member (with the function as a function member), or it can a static local variable in the function, or a namespace scope variable. I think I'd use the class data member.
- *Create names from high resolution time stamps.*
  This limits the rate of name generation, but file creation is a time consuming action so the rate should not be a practical problem. And on the positive side, each file's name then says when it was created.
- *Use UUIDs.*
  An UUID, a *Universally Unique IDentifier*, is 128 bit pseudo-random identifier that is extremely unlikely to be identical to any other generated UUID. Unfortunately the C++ standard library doesn't provide UUID support. But there is available UUID generation for every commonly used general computing platform.

If you want the time stamps but without the rate limitation (resolution of the timestamp), then you can combine it with the counter approach, i.e. using both.

I would not really recommend UUIDs, because they're difficult for us humans to remember and recognize. Just moving your gaze from the debugger or a trace, to a directory display, the UUID you saw may be gone from your mind. Sequence numbers and time stamps are more human-friendly.

---

Regarding

> **”** I Am Not Willing To Use If-Else Since I Need A lots and lots of files

… that's a nonsense requirement.

To get better answers to your questions, just state the problem and don't add limiting requirements based on your evaluation of the goodness or not of some envisioned (non-) solution.

Comment: @cheers-and-hth-alf Thanks but First of all, I don't need temporary files. I need some permanent files that must stay until I wish to remove them. Second, I just can't use if-else if I need a number of files so I had to put that limitation in order to filter the answers that I might have got and to avoid the answers that I don't actually need. :/